# public health measures (what's the meaning of 'measures')

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> Reduction or elimination of these factors may require societal action, such as public awareness and public health measures.

definition of measure: 1.   an amount or degree of something
[count] She felt equal measures of hope and fear.

2. usually singular
   The province has gained a large measure of freedom.

Their children want a greater measure of independence. [=they want more independence]

The coating provides a measure of protection [=provides some protection] against corrosion.

The proposal has been met with a measure [=a certain amount] of skepticism.

The alarm system provides an added measure of security. [=provides more security]

[noncount] The show mixes comedy and drama in equal measure. [=in equal amounts]

[noncount] He returned their hostility in full measure. [=he was as hostile toward them as they were toward him]

[noncount] The company's success is due in no small measure to her talents. [=its success is largely due to her talents]

[noncount] Their actions were motivated in large measure by a desire for revenge.

[noncount] An occasion like this calls for some measure of decorum.

3. [count]
   a.  something (such as a cup or a ruler) that is used to measure things see also TAPE MEASURE
   b.  a unit used in measuring something see also MADE-TO-MEASURE
   The meter is a measure of length.

The dictionary includes a table of weights and measures.

4. [count]
   an action planned or taken to achieve a desired result
   The legislature has passed a measure aimed at protecting consumers.
5. [count]
   a sign or indication of something
6. [count]
   usually singular
   Wealth is not a measure of happiness.
7. [count]
   a way of judging something
   The company is a success by any measure.

Are IQ tests the best measure of intelligence?

8. [chiefly US, music] [count]
   a part of a line of written music that is between two vertical lines or the group of beats between these lines
   a brief clarinet solo in the third measure

Can you hum a few measures [=bars] of that song?

https://dict.naver.com/enendict/#/entry/enen/c39c64de21214f37b2fd6ce1660da30e

Comment: Your 4th item fits the context quite well.

Comment: Definitely definition 4.

Answer (score 1):

It is obviously the 4th definition. The use of "societal action" already suggests its an action taken to do something!